# Update in a document based on $or filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have collection like

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("565ff61d454231a81753866a"),
"tripMembers" : [ 
        {
            "username" : "akshay.kumar@gmail.com",
            "contact" : null,
            "userId" : "1234999",
            "accept" : 2,
            "_id" : ObjectId("565ff61d454231a817538664")
        }, 
        {
            "username" : "akshay@gmail.co",
            "contact" : null,
            "userId" : "",
            "accept" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("565ff61d454231a817538665")
        }]
}
```

and I want to update a key of a object in array.I am using following query but it's not working

```
db.trips.update({
    $or :[
        {"tripMembers.username" : "akshay.kumar@gmail.com"},
       {"tripMembers.contact": "1234999" }]
    },
    {"_id" :ObjectId("565ff61d454231a81753866a")},
    {$set : {"tripMembers.accept" :1}
})
```

It's giving me error ***The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: tripMembers.$.accept***

If I'm trying same query only one condition in `$or` operator its working fine as

```
db.trips.update({
    $or :[
        {"tripMembers.username" : "akshay.kumar@gmail.com"}  
    },
    {"_id" :ObjectId("565ff61d454231a81753866a")},
    {$set : {"tripMembers.accept" :1}
})
```

Don't know, where i am wrong.Any help appreciable.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `{"_id" :ObjectId("565ff61d454231a81753866a")}`? It looks like you have a syntax error with the update and it starts there. Your `$set`` seems to be the third parameter where it should be the second.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be:

```
b.trips.update({
    $and:
        [{$or :[
            {"tripMembers.username" : "akshay.kumar@gmail.com"}  
        ]},
        {"_id" :ObjectId("565ff61d454231a81753866a")}]
    },
    {$set : {"tripMembers.accept" :1}})
```

?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. Please revise your post and fix brackets

Answer (score 0):

the closing ] brace is simply in the incorrect position.

```
db.trips.update({
    $or :[
        {"tripMembers.username" : "akshay.kumar@gmail.com"},
       {"tripMembers.contact": "1234999" }] <<--- no closing brace here
    },
    {"_id" :ObjectId("565ff61d454231a81753866a")}, << -- your update clause as David points out. This will wipe out all subdocs and leave only _id. urp!
    {$set : {"tripMembers.accept" :1} << -- not executed. irrelevant
})
```

try

```
db.trips.update({
    $or :[
        {"tripMembers.username" : "akshay.kumar@gmail.com"},
       {"tripMembers.contact": "1234999" },
       {"_id" :ObjectId("565ff61d454231a81753866a")}],
    {$set : {"tripMembers.accept" :1}
})
```

further according to your data. a minor oversite.

```
       "contact" : null,
        "userId" : "1234999",
```

so likely  $or ... {"tripMembers.**userId**": "1234999" },